# saveFileDialog Сохранение под разными именами

Tags: c#

Как сделать чтобы например если нажать на кнопку 1 документ сохранялся под одним именем, если нажимал другую .
Есть такой диалог для первой кнопки

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_EUR");
```

как сделать чтобы не писать тучу кода ради пары букв.
Вторая кнопка сохраняет под именем

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_GBP");
```

мысль была через if else прописать но button не имеет события click
И есть ли возможность сделать задержку появления формы?
Чтобы она через секунды 2 - 3 появлялась

Answer (score 1):

можно еще sender преобразовать в кнопку и вытащить name, или посмотреть другие атрибуты самой кнопки. тоже не проверял

```
    Button b = sender as Button;
    saveFileDialog.FileName = String.Format("{yyyyMMdd}_{1}", DateTime.Now, b.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Как то так (не проверял):

```
saveFileDialog.FileName = String.Format("{yyyyMMdd}_{1}", DateTime.Now, sender.Tag);
```

Насчет задержки появления формы слишком общий вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

про задержку

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Нет, вешать форму никто не просил...

Comment: в фоновом потоке можно

Comment: В фоновом потоке нельзя показывать диалог.

Comment: про диалог никто не говорил )

Comment: Ну да, замечательная пара ответов: вот так ты можешь показать диалог, а вот так, если сам догадаешься до создания потока (да-да, догадаюсь, до показа диалога не догадался, а до создания потока догадаюсь), сделать задержку. И неважно, что эти способы не совмещаются в одно действие.

Comment: а ты прав ) ну есть вариант в отдельном потоке и после показа диалога замораживать первую форму. если ТС вернется, могу нарисовать